# How to loop through list(map(string)) in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am creating a google_compute_instance resource through Terraform.

I need to attach a boot disk and an additional disk to it. So in locals I declare like the below, and pass the necessary variables

```
locals
{
 boot_disk = [
    {
      source_image = var.bootSourceImage
      disk_size_gb = var.bootDiskSizeGb
      type    = var.bootDiskType
      auto_delete  = var.bootDiskAutoDelete
      boot         = "true"
      device_name="${var.machineName}-boot"
      disk_type="PERSISTENT"
    },
  ]

  add_disk= [
    {
      source_image = var.bootSourceImage
      disk_size_gb = var.disk1DiskSizeGb
     type=var.disk1DiskType
     device_name=var.disk1DiskName
     disk_type="PERSISTENT"
     auto_delete=var.disk1DiskAutoDelete
     boot="false"
    }
  ]
}
all_disks=concat(local.boot_disk,local.add_disk) //I concatenate them
```

I need to attach a policy to the disks which gets created so I use this block

```
    resource "google_compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment" "attached-disk" {
     //Here I need to loop through all_disk
 for_each=local.all_disk.boot=false?current_disk:[] //From the all_disks I need to filter if this not boot disk then get the value ex. all_disk.boot=false then return the disk to for_each

    }

    resource "google_compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment" "boot-disk" {
     //Here I need to loop through all_disk
 for_each=local.all_disk.boot=true?current_disk:[] //From the all_disks I need to filter if this is boot disk then get the value like all_disk.boot=true
    }
```

How to loop through all_disks using for_each and return the current disk based on the boot value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive one collection from another using [`for` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for), which includes the possibility of [filtering elements](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for#filtering-elements) using the optional `if` clause.

In your case it seems like your goal is to have your "attached disk" resource have one instance per element that has `boot` set to `false`, and your "boot disk" resource have all of the remaining elements where `boot` is set to `true`. If that's true then I would suggest the following two expressions:

```
resource "google_compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment" "attached-disk" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in local.all_disk : k => v
    if !v.boot
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk_resource_policy_attachment" "boot-disk" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in local.all_disk : k => v
    if v.boot
  }
}
```

This works by testing the `if` expression for each `v`, which are the values in the mapping `local.all_disk`. If the expression evaluates to `true` then the item will be included in the result, and otherwise it will not.

---

Note that you currently have your `boot` attributes defined as being strings rather than boolean values. This can work as long as the string is exactly `"true"` or `"false"` because Terraform can automatically coerce those strings into boolean values, but to make your configuration easier to follow for future maintainers (who might not be so familiar with Terraform's automatic conversion rules) I would typically advise using the most appropriate type rather than relying automatic conversions, by setting the `boot` attribute to be either `true` or `false`, the two actual boolean values in the Terraform language.

If you *do* use `"true"` and `"false"` then you need to be careful with how you test those expressions. `!"true"` produces `false` because Terraform knows that the operand of unary `!` is always boolean, but `"true" == true` will return `false` because two values of different types can never be equal and the `==` operator doesn't give Terraform any hint about what automatic type conversion you might have intended.

Comment: Thank you! just need clarification on the following statement     for k, v in local.all_disk : k => v
What is k => v means?